# Get Row from NSArray

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, row

Hello i get a json that looks like this:

```
  features: (
    {
    attributes =         {
        Gecontroleerd = Ja;
    };
    geometry =         {
        x = "5.968097965285907";
        y = "52.50707112779077";
    };
}
)
```

From this code:

```
NSDictionary *root = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *data = [root objectForKey:@"features"];
NSLog(@"features: %@", data );

for (NSArray *row in data) {
    NSString *latitude = row[5];
    NSString *longitude = row[7];
    NSString *crimeDescription = @"test";
    NSString *address = @"banaan";
```

And u need to x values 5.968097965285907 for latitude
and y values 52.50707112779077 for longitude

But i get this error:

```
 [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance   0x14831450
 2012-11-14 10:10:59.000 ArrestPlotter[6330:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught  exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14831450'
 *** First throw call stack:
(0x1860012 0x1655e7e 0x18eb4bd 0x184fbbc 0x184f94e 0x2dbc 0x3b8f 0x1cc1e 0x16696b0 0xfa0035 0x17e3f3f 0x17e396f 0x1806734 0x1805f44 0x1805e1b 0x224a7e3 0x224a668 0x4a765c 0x25bd 0x24e5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Does anyone wich row i need to select?

I guess that the only thing is that the row number needs to be changed. Or maybe there should be something like this : [1][5]. Im not quite sure how this works

Comment: If you really  "get a json that looks like this" your json is invalid. It is just an NSDictionary description.

Comment: I agree, this JSON is not valid, post the actual JSON (and verify it at jsonlint.com first)

Comment: No i get a json, but i do: NSArray *data = [root objectForKey:@"features"]; and then i get the NSArray..
Sorry if i said that wrong

Comment: It's valid since he's logging it after deserialization

Comment: What should i change? NSArray *data to NSDictionary * data?

Comment: @Babboe I didn't see that YOU put "features:" in the NSLog so actually it's an array but what's inside are dictionaries

Comment: @Babboe would you provide us with the result of NSLog(@"features: %@", data );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *data = [root objectForKey:@"features"];
NSLog(@"features: %@", data );

for (NSDictionary *dic in data) {
  NSDictionary geometry = [dic objectForKey:@"geometry"];
  // Do what you want..
  NSString *myAwesomeX = [geometry objectForKey:@"x"];
  NSString *myAwesomeY = [geometry objectForKey:@"y"];
}
```

Comment: But how do i get the longitude then from this one? and the latitude?. I cant use the row function anymore

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are trying to send a selector message to object row, that is in memory a *NSDictionary* (NSCFDictionary?) object, and you are trying to manage it like a *NSArray*.

The method `objectAtIndexedSubscript` (is underlying called by row[5] and row[7]) exists in NSDictionary, but no in NSArray.

Change

```
for (NSArray *row in data) {
```

by

```
for (NSDictionary *row in data) {
```

Also, you have to change the management of data inside for, look at the result of your log statement and act accord whit it.

I hope this will help!